# How to solve a two variable equation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Suppose $m,n$ are positive constants,there is an equation $m|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2-n\lambda_1\bar{\lambda_2}-n\lambda_2\bar{\lambda_1}=0$,where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are nonzero complex numbers.

Does there exist solutions to this equation?

Comment: Let $\lambda_1=a+bi,\lambda_2=c+di$,where $a,b,c,d$ are unkown,I can get $m(a^2+b^2)+c^2+d^2-(2ac+2bd)n=0$,I don't how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1 = |\lambda_1| e^{i \phi_1}$, and $\lambda_2 = |\lambda_2| e^{i \phi_2}$.

First note that the term $-n\lambda_1\bar{\lambda_2}-n\lambda_2\bar{\lambda_1} = -2 n |\lambda_1||\lambda_2| \cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$. So let $-2 n \cos(\phi_1-\phi_2) = 2 q$, then we have

$$
0 = m|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2+ 2 q |\lambda_1||\lambda_2|\\
= (|\lambda_2|+ q |\lambda_1|)^2 + (m-q^2)|\lambda_1|^2
$$

Solutions exist for $q^2 >m$ which is  $n^2 \cos^2(\phi_1-\phi_2) > m$.